# How to add filters on columns with server side option

Tags: javascript, datatables

I have datatables and filters on columns on my script and it works great but ony when I generate table by body (DOM). When I want to generate table by ajax (server side option) it not working. How can I use server side and filters on columns? I need tip how to get query by ajax from select filter.

```
       initComplete: function () {
        this.api().columns('.select-filter').every( function () {
            var column = this;
            var name = column.header().innerHTML;
            var col = $('<div class=\"filters\"></div>').appendTo(  \".filters-group\" );
            var select = $('<select class=\'form-control select2\'><option value=\"\">Wszystko</option></select>')
                .on( 'change', function () {
                    var val = $.fn.dataTable.util.escapeRegex(
                        $(this).val()
                    );

                    column
                        .search( val ? '^'+val+'$' : '', true, false )
                        .draw();
                } );

            column
            .data()
            .unique()
            .sort()
            .each(function(d, j) {
              var val = $.fn.dataTable.util.escapeRegex(d);
              if (column.search() === \"^\" + val + \"$\") {
                select.append(
                  '<option value=\"' + d + '\" selected=\"selected\">' + d + \"</option>\"
                );
              } else {
                select.append('<option value=\"' + d + '\">' + d + \"</option>\");
              }
            });
            var label = $('<label class=\'filters-label\'>'+name+'</label>');
            var form = $('<div class=\'form-group\'></div>');
            col.append(form);
            form.append(label);
            form.append(select);
        } );
    },
```

Comment: If I understand your context right, server-side filtering is normally done at the SQL level.  Short answer is that you use AJAX to call a Server-Side script that generates a SQL query based on the parameters in the data object you pass to it.  Then the Server-Side script builds the table and you return the table as innerHTML to the container you want to update.  That said, without more info about your server-side language or type of SQL database, I can't really be more specific than that.

Comment: Or if you wish to be strict about your separation of interface you could use the Server-Side script to generate XML, JSON, or what you are using then call the function that rebuilds your table.

Comment: Datatables serachbox is querying my SQL script by GET and ajax- this is standard function when serverside option is set to true. But how can I add values from filters to this query?

Comment: Ah, I did not mouse over the datatables tag to see that is is jQuery Plugin, but I did take a quick look at the documentation.  Did you also set "processing": true as shown here: https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/server_side